# How to pass a nested generic parameter to typscript type declaration?

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

I have a type declaration

```
type IfExtendsThen<Tin, Tx, To1, To2> = Tin extends Tx ? To1 : To2;

type AllPropertiesAsObservable<T> = {
  [key in keyof T]: IfExtendsThen<T[key], string | number | boolean, Observable<T[key]>, AllPropertiesAsObservable<T[key]>>;
} & Observable<T>;
```

it creates a mapped type in which every property of type string, number or boolean is converted to an observable recursively.

it works fine, but now I want to pass Observable type as input too...
i.e. something like this

```
type AllPropertiesAsObservable<T, Tobservable extends Observable> = {
  [key in keyof T]: IfExtendsThen<T[key], string | number | boolean, Tobservable <T[key]>, AllPropertiesAsObservable<T[key], Tobservable >>;
} & Tobservable <T>;
```

So, that I can use it somewhat like this

```
let obj = AllPropertiesAsObservable<Xyz, BehaviorSubject>;
```

now, every porperty of type `Xyz` of string, number or boolean type is converted to BehaviorSubject.
however, this gives an error,

```
Generic type 'Observable<T>' requires 1 type argument(s).
```

In `AllPropertiesAsObservable` declaration.

note: `Observable` here is from `rxjs` library.

Any suggestion how can I achieve this?

Comment: `type AllPropertiesAsObservable<T, Tobservable extends Observable<T>>` ?

Comment: i have tried that, but it will not let me use `Tobservable<T[key]>`

Comment: HKT is not supported in TS, so type constructors cannot be passed to another type constructors. probably you need some hack like https://github.com/pelotom/hkts